# Finding maximum value before sequence repeats in R

Tags: r, logic, bigdata

I have a data set that looks like the following

```
xx = c(1:5, 1:9, 1:7)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I would like to know the index of 1 and the maximum value before the sequence begins again.  For example:

```
[1] 1, 1
[2] 5, 5
[3] 6, 1
[4] 14, 9
[5] 15, 1
[6] 21, 7
```

and so on.....

Comment: You should use `dput` on a subset of your data to make this reproducible

Comment: @Pdubbs have any suggestions in how to solve the problem?

Comment: see answer below

Comment: @Pdubbs thanks for the answer but I've updated my question so that 1) there is a reproducible example and 2) more closely matches what I'm having a hard problem with.

Comment: are the subsequences always continuous e.g. `1:10` or can they be disjoint e.g. `c(1,2,5,9)`. Similarly are they all ordered, or do they just start with 1?

Comment: @Pdubbs yes sir, always continuous, in order and always start with 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be answered with a somewhat ugly (but efficient!) `lapply`:

```
a<-lapply(1:length(xx),function(x) {
    if(x==length(xx)){c(x,xx[x])}else{
      if(xx[x] == 1){c(x,1)}else{
        if(xx[x]>xx[x+1]){c(x,xx[x])}
         }
       }
})
matrix(unlist(a),ncol = 2,byrow = T)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be (Assuming that the `vector` contains only sequence elements)

```
v1 <- which(xx == 1)
v2 <- c(rbind(v1, c(v1[-1]-1, length(xx))))
cbind(ind = v2, value = xx[v2])
#      ind value
#[1,]   1     1
#[2,]   5     5
#[3,]   6     1
#[4,]  14     9
#[5,]  15     1
#[6,]  21     7
```

---

Or another option is to do a `split` on the sequence of elements of 'xx' and get the first and last elements of each `list`

```
ind <- unlist(lapply(split(seq_along(xx), cumsum(xx==1)), function(x) x[c(1, length(x))]))
cbind(ind, value = xx[ind])
```